# How to convert jeprof output to human readable format?

Tags: java, malloc, jemalloc, java-native-library

Failing while converting hprof output to gif format.

```
jeprof --show_bytes --gif /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java jeprof.*.heap > /tmp/profile_1.gif
```

Exception:

```
Can't exec "objdump": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/jeprof line 4463.
objdump -h /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: apt-get install graphviz binutils
Resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install binutils

```
apt-get install binutils
```

https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/97659/

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-tools/issues/73